# Using Recursion to Reverse String - C

Tags: c

I don't know if I just don't understand arrays or what, but I've been looking for the problem in this code for the last couple of hours. When I run it, I get an infinite loop of returns.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char string2Reverse[80], int start, int end);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char string[80];

    int cntr;
    for(cntr = 0; cntr < 80; cntr++)
        string[cntr] = '\0';

    int start = 0, end;

    while((scanf("s", string)) != EOF)
    {
    end = 0;
    printf("%s ", string);

    while(string[end] != '\0')
        end++;

    end--;
    reverse(string, start, end);
    end++;
    printf("%s\n\n", string);

    for(cntr = 0; cntr < end; cntr++)
        string[cntr] = '\0';
    }
}

void reverse(char string2Reverse[80], int start, int end)
{
    if(string2Reverse[start] != string2Reverse[end] && start != end)
    {
    char temp = string2Reverse[start];
    string2Reverse[start] = string2Reverse[end];
    string2Reverse[end] = temp;
    reverse(string2Reverse, start + 1, end - 1);
    }
}
```

Any help would be awesome! I can't seem to find my problem.

Comment: It is often helpful to only provide as much code as needed to exhibit the problem. Here replacing input with constants would be a good idea as it makes automatic verification harder.

Answer (score 2):

If end-start is not even, you'll infinite loop because start will != end ever .. also i dont' know if you actually want to be comparing the `string2Reverse[start] != string2Reverse[end]` like that, that means if there is a place in the string where there is an 'a' and in the balanced position on the other side of a string there is also an 'a', it'll terminate. Try this:

```
void reverse(char string2Reverse[80], int start, int end)
{
    if(start < end)
    {
    char temp = string2Reverse[start];
    string2Reverse[start] = string2Reverse[end];
    string2Reverse[end] = temp;
    reverse(string2Reverse, start + 1, end - 1);
    }
}
```

---

And as everyone else pointed out here, you need "%s" instead of "s" in your scanf, the reason why you're looping right now is because end starts off as -1 (since it was a zero len string), so obviously start is increasing and end is decreasing, so your termination condition never met.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf`'s format to read strings is `%s`, it seems you're missing the percent sign.

Answer (score 1):

`while((scanf("s", string)) != EOF)` should be `while((scanf("%s", &string)) != EOF)` dont forget % and &.